# Creating a unique dummy object

Tags: python, python-3.x, constants, identity, initialization

I need to create a dummy object to mark an uninitialized element in a list (obviously, dictionary would have been a better choice, but I need a list because of heavy memory constraints).

I am thinking to use for this purpose an object with the following properties:

1. It doesn't evaluate as equal to any other object but itself.
2. A reference to it cannot be created other than from the original reference (through assignment or parameter passing).

`None` satisfies the first but not the second requirement (as it may created anywhere in the program by using literal `None`).

One approach that should work, I think, is:

```
  UNINITIALIZED_VALUE = object() # will be compared for == through identity
  a = [1, UNINITIALIZED_VALUE, 2, UNINITIALIZED_VALUE]
  a[1] == a[3] # True
  a[0] == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE # False
```

I wanted to double check that I'm not missing any potential problem with this approach. (I'm using Python 3.)

Comment: Except that you aren't testing with identity, you are testing with equality. use `a[0] is UNINITIALIZED_VALUE`. Now, for simple objects that doesn't actually make any *difference*. But it's the principle of the thing. ;-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro I added an answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's how everybody does it. Do note that you can't set arbitrary attributes on such an object though.

Comment: Thx.. For arbitrary attributes, I normally use `x = lambda : 0`. Is this ok?

Comment: That works, but usually we create a new class derived from `object` with an empty (i.e. `pass`) block and instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only creating an answer because I need more space to reply to an interesting comment by @Lennart Regebro. His comment made me think about whether `a[0] is UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` or `a[0] == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` is more appropriate.

I think it is up to me (the developer who designs `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE`) whether I promise support for `is`, `==`, or both. After all, a user shouldn't assume anything unless an explicit promise is given (since if he relies on an undocumented behavior, the implementation may change and break his code).

And I actually think it would be better if I (as the designer) promised that both `is` and `==` will work for testing if the value is uninitialized. Without support for `==`, a user won't be able to write something like this:

```
def remove_duplicates(list_):
  return list(set(list_)) # requires that UNINITIALIZED_VALUE supports ==
```

There's just one minor problem. As a designer of `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` I can easily guarantee that it behaves correctly with `==` when it's on the LHS (my original one-line implementation does). However, I can't guarantee that it behaves correctly when it's on the RHS. After all, if the object on the LHS is crazy aggressive about its comparison semantics, and compares equal to everything in sight, I can't do anything about it. Arguably, such aggressive behavior is almost a bug; that's why I consider this a minor problem.